# Cannot update a single widget after all widgets are built

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate

I’ve developed an application to organize quick menu for dinner. There are 6 recipes as list tiles. I have a scoreboard also. Scoreboard shows the total value of randomly generated menu. Score is calculated according to some numeric properties of recipes.

The problem is that I cannot update the scoreboard after all recipe tiles are loaded. When I call

```
setState(){
  _score = _getScore();
}
```

all widgets are rebuilt. Then, all recipe widgets redrawn again with new recipes.

It causes an infinite loop of rebuild.

_score variable is used in scoreboard widget.

The question is,
How can I update only scoreboard widget without triggering all widgets to reduild?

**---- EDIT / ADDED ----**

A screenshot and related codes given below.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
            child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                  _buildScoreboard(),
                  _buildRecipeTile(context, RecipeType.maindish),
                  _buildRecipeTile(context, RecipeType.soup),
                  _buildRecipeTile(context, RecipeType.salad),
                  _buildRecipeTile(context, RecipeType.dessert),
                  _buildRecipeTile(context, RecipeType.bakery),
                  _buildRecipeTile(context, RecipeType.drink),
                ],
             ),
         ),
    );
  }
```

I want to update `Text('$_score')`

```
Widget _buildScoreboard() {
    return Text('$_score');
  }
```

There is a `FutureBuilder` in recipe tile widget. And, we calculate score after each tile is loaded: `_score = _getScore();`

```
Widget _buildRecipeTile(BuildContext context, RecipeType recipeType) {
    CollectionReference cr = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meals');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: cr.where("type", isEqualTo: recipeType.index).get().then((value) {
        return value.docs.elementAt(random.nextInt(value.size));
      }),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            ...
            _score = _getScore();
            ...
          }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the widget that you want to update (scoreboard?), let's call it  `YourNormalWidget` You need to wrap it in a `StatefulBuilder`.

This will give you access to a new `setState` that works only for this widget (not the rest of the build)

**Code:**

```
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setPartialStateOnly) {
        return YourNormalWidget(

          //your normal code... then:
            setPartialStateOnly(() {
              yourVariable = updatedValues
            });
        )
```

Not that instead of the normal `setState`, I am calling the new `setPartialStateOnly`

Let me know if this does not help.

Comment: I strongly believe that your solution would work. :D But I couldn't apply it to my code. I've added my code snippets to my post. Please check it.

Comment: I've solved the problem using `ValueListenableBuilder`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html